# The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access with Snapshot Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, .net-core

I am trying to open a Snapshot that I am logging in Azure in Visual Studio 15.5 and I get the following error

> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access

If I attempt to debug with managed code, I get this exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x0C492A36 in 8acbe77983bb43b4bad3ef7f2224a765.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

I have tried running VS as Admin but this isn't resolved. Is it a symbol loading issue? Not sure how to debug this

Comment: Are you sure that the error described is not what happened to the process that was dumped? That is the sort of message I woud expect if your process had an access violation and terminated.

Comment: No I know what the exception is, it is NullReferenceException. I am testing Snapshot Debugging and want to make sure I am knowledged on the setup.

Comment: Please contact us at snapshothelp@microsoft.com for support. FWIW, I think @SoronelHaetir is correct, but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: @pharring done!

Comment: @pharring, how many people watch that DL, I was hoping to get a quick answer for this.

Comment: We didn't receive any email to the DL from you. There are 7 people on the alias, but it is not 24x7 support. However, we did get an alert from another thread you started elsewhere and I've tried to help you on there.

Comment: I support what SoronelHaetir said above, this looks like process crash. Access Violation Exceptions (0xC0000005) thrown from native code do commonly show up as NullReferenceException in managed code.